# Parsing a growing logfile

Tags: ruby, logging, parsing

I want to do a logfile parser using ruby, this parser should parse the log file while it grows. It should parse line by line until the end and then wait (somehow?) for more lines to come, so my question is how to best handle it growing?

edit:
Would prefer a portable way of doing this, even though my logfile is on Windows (for the moment).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can use [Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx).  You tell Windows (with [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx)) to monitor the directory c:/foo/logs, then Windows updates your handle when something happens in that directory.  At that point, you check to see if the change involves a file you care about.

Ruby has bindings for the Win32 API, and there is [an example](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/36807) of getting these notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good script posted at http://www.biterscripting.com/SS_WebLogParser.html . It is a sample script written for web server logs, but can be used as a starting point for writing your own log parser for logs of any kind. To use it in a continuous way, while the log file keeps growing, here is a script.

```
# Script LogParser.txt
# Go in a continuous loop, sleeping 1 hr each time.
while (true)
do
    # The number of lines in the log file the last time we checked is in following
    # variable. Initially, it will be 0.
    var int lines_old

    # Read the log file into a str variable.
    var str log ; cat "file.log" > $log

    # Get the number of lines found this time.
    var str lines_new ; set $lines_new = { len -e $log } 

    # Strip off the first $lines lines.
    lex -e (makestr(int($lines))+"]") $log > null

    # The new lines are now available in $log. Process them with something similar to
    # SS_WebLogParser script.

    # Update $lines_old, then, sleep.
    set $lines_old = $lines_new
    sleep 3600                                  # 3600 seconds = 1 hour
done
```

To try,

1. Save this script into, say, C:\LogParser.txt (since you are on
   windows).
2. Download biterscripting. Google it up.
3. Call our script by entering the following command.

   script "\LogParser.txt"

If you need to use any of their sample scripts, install them with the following command.

```
script "http://www.biterscripting.com/Download/SS_AllSamples.txt"
```

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can use IO.popen to get a file stream on the pipe of the growing result of a command line. Then use the readline function in while loop.
Here is an example with the "adb logcat" command which get the live growing log of an Android device :

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

IO.popen("adb logcat") do |io|
    while line = io.readline
        line.strip!

        # Process here
        print "#{line}\n" 
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

For a file, it is a little different. I would "readline" in polling on the file stream.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

File.open("test.log") do |io|
    loop do 
        begin
            line = io.readline
            line.strip!
        rescue
            sleep 0.2
            retry
        end

        # Process here
        print "#{line}\n"
    end 
end
```